# How does the getWritableDatabase() cache work?

Tags: android, sqlite, caching

I understand that when the getWritableDatabase() is invoked, then according to the doc:

> Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.

1. how does the write back to the database occur exactly?
2. Does it write to the cached database first and then to the actual database?
3. In case its written to cache first,when do the cached contents get written back to the actual storage?

Comment: Storing an instance of `SQLiteDatabase` object for future use as in the documentation you posted is different from database disk I/O caching.

Answer (score 0):

The cache mentioned here is not a data cache; it simply means that the `SQLiteDatabase` object is reused by other `getWritableDatabase()` calls as long as it is not yet closed.
This avoids having to reopen the database file.

Writing of new data to disk is handled automatically by the database at the end of each transaction.

Comment: So this means basically I fetch the same database file each time I write or read ? So doesnt this make this as slow as accessing internal storage for file ?

Comment: There are other caches: the database has a page cache, and the OS has a file cache. But these are not related to your question.